# How can I program a function key to open a program with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I got a large print keyboard for my husband and want to program the function keys like I can with his Logitech keyboard.  I want F1 to open Quicken, F2 to open Outlook, etc.  If I can just get the syntax for one I can do the rest of them.  Thank you.

I tried using AutoHotKey on my own but I'm probably doing something wrong because I can't figure out what to put in the script to just, say, open quicken or open outlook.    All I need is exactly what to put in the script and how it should look.  I'm confused about the colons :: and other symbols.  Thank you.